# MT5 opening order returns "None"

Tags: python, metatrader5

I'm new and am trying to build a python bot for MT5. i tried to send a trade in MT5 over python, however it always returns "None".

I've input all the required information, could it be because of decimal error?

```
import os
from datetime import datetime
import MetaTrader5 as mt5
import requests
import datetime as dt  # for dealing with times
import numpy as np
import json
import pandas as pd
import pytz

ea_magic_number = 9986989 # if you want to give every bot a unique identifier

def open_trade(action, symbol, lot, sl_points, tp_points, deviation):
    '''https://www.mql5.com/en/docs/integration/python_metatrader5/mt5ordersend_py
    '''
    # prepare the buy request structure
    symbol_info = mt5.symbol_info(symbol)

    if action == 'buy':
        trade_type = mt5.ORDER_TYPE_BUY
        price = mt5.symbol_info_tick(symbol).ask
    elif action =='sell':
        trade_type = mt5.ORDER_TYPE_SELL
        price = mt5.symbol_info_tick(symbol).bid
    point = mt5.symbol_info(symbol).point


    action_request = {
        "action": mt5.TRADE_ACTION_DEAL,
        "symbol": symbol,
        "volume": lot,
        "type": trade_type,
        "price": price,
        "sl": round(price - sl_points * point,5),
        "tp": price + tp_points * point,
        "deviation": deviation,
        "magic": ea_magic_number,
        "comment": "sent by python",
        "type_time": mt5.ORDER_TIME_GTC, # good till cancelled
        "type_filling": mt5.ORDER_FILLING_RETURN
    }
    # send a trading request
    result = mt5.order_send(action_request)
    return result, action_request

def close_trade(action, action_request, result, deviation):
    '''https://www.mql5.com/en/docs/integration/python_metatrader5/mt5ordersend_py
    '''
    # create a close request
    symbol = action_request['symbol']

    if action == 'buy':
        trade_type = mt5.ORDER_TYPE_BUY
        price = mt5.symbol_info_tick(symbol).ask
    elif action =='sell':
        trade_type = mt5.ORDER_TYPE_SELL
        price = mt5.symbol_info_tick(symbol).bid
    position_id=result.order
    lot = action_request['volume']

    action_request={
        "action": mt5.TRADE_ACTION_DEAL,
        "symbol": symbol,
        "volume": lot,
        "type": mt5.ORDER_TYPE_SELL,
        "position": position_id,
        "price": price,
        "deviation": deviation,
        "magic": ea_magic_number,
        "comment": "python script close",
        "type_time": mt5.ORDER_TIME_GTC, # good till cancelled
        "type_filling": mt5.ORDER_FILLING_RETURN,
    }
    # send a close request
    result=mt5.order_send(action_request)

currency_pair = "GBPUSD"


# establish connection to MetaTrader 5 terminal
if not mt5.initialize(login=31706337, server="MetaQuotes-Demo",password="mzhjm8hi"):
    print("initialize() failed, error code =", mt5.last_error())
    quit()


trade = open_trade('buy', currency_pair, 10, 500, 2000, 10)
print(trade)
```

Result:
C:\Users\andyq\PycharmProjects\BinanceTrading\venv\Scripts\python.exe "C:/Users/andyq/PycharmProjects/BinanceTrading/data preparation.py"

```
(None, {'action': 1, 'symbol': 'GBPUSD', 'volume': 10, 'type': 0, 'price': 1.26224, 'sl': 1.25724, 'tp': 1.28224, 'deviation': 10, 'magic': 9986989, 'comment': 'sent by python', 'type_time': 0, 'type_filling': 2})
```

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: The problem may be arising from mt5.order_send(). Check if it is working fine.

Comment: how do i check if the mt5.order_send() is working? there is another function order_check which returns None when i tried.


https://www.mql5.com/en/docs/integration/python_metatrader5/mt5ordercheck_py

Answer (score 11):

volume should be a Double
so:

```
'volume': 10
```

should be:

```
'volume': 10.0
```

Comment: This saved me a lot of time. Kudos!

Comment: Thanks didn't pay attention to that

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same problem, for solving this issue you should check all the data types in the request dictionary.
volume, stop loss, take profit and price should be float values and keep in mind the order ticket should be int

Comment: Please provide code that will help the OP to understand what needs to be done.